# Serenity CI/CD Azure Pipeline: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\V\01-Au04\_work\36\s\target\site\serenity'

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, serenity

Team: When I run a manual execution on Azure DevOps I'm getting the next errors:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\V\01-Au04\_work\36\s\target\site\serenity'
    Archive files

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\V\01-Au04\_work\36\s\target\site\serenity'
Archive files

Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: E:\V\01-Au04\_work\36\s\target\site\serenity\serenity-summary.html
Publish Single page report

Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment type=replacedhtml;name=content;]E:\V\01-Au04\_work\36/s/target/site/serenity/serenity-summary.html' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
Publish HTML report

Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Cannot upload task attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file not exist on disk')
Publish HTML report
```

and I'm also getting this warning:

Warning

```
Directory 'E:\V\01-Au04\_work\36\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'Full report'.
Publish Full report
```

I have here my YML file:

```
parameters:
  - name: tag
    displayName: Tag
    type: string
    default: '@UI'

  - name: environment
    displayName: Environment
    values:
      - stage
    default: stage

  - name: browser
    displayName: Browser
    values:
      - chrome
    default: chrome

  - name: headless
    displayName: Headless
    values:
      - true
      - false
    default: true

trigger: none
pr: none

stages:
  - stage: run_maven
    pool: Dev-AutomatedTests
    displayName: Run Production UI regression test
    jobs:
      - job: Build_and_execute
        timeoutInMinutes: 270
        steps:

          - task: Maven@4
            displayName: Execute tests
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
              goals: 'test'
              options: 'clean verify -Denvironment="${{ parameters.environment }}" -D"cucumber.filter.tags"="${{ parameters.tag }}" -D"headless.mode"="${{ parameters.headless }} -Daccess=$(DOOR_ACCESS)'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/SERENITY-JUNIT-*.xml'
              testRunTitle: 'Prod UI Tests'
              ${{ if and(eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'), not(contains(parameters.pool, 'vmss'))) }}:
                javaHomeOption: 'Path'
                jdkVersionOption: 1.11
                jdkDirectory: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.1.1-1.el8_6.x86_64'
                mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
                mavenDirectory: '/opt/maven'
              ${{ if and(eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'), contains(parameters.pool, 'vmss')) }}:
                javaHomeOption: 'Path'
                jdkVersionOption: 1.11
                jdkDirectory: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64'
                mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
                mavenDirectory: '/usr/share/maven'
              ${{ if eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT') }}:
                javaHomeOption: 'Path'
                jdkDirectory: $(java_home)
                mavenVersionOption: 'Default'

          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: Archive files
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(agent.builddirectory)/s/target/site/serenity'
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: 'zip'
              archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Test_Results_$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              replaceExistingArchive: true

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: Publish Full report
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'Full report'
              publishLocation: 'Container'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: Publish Single page report
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(agent.builddirectory)/s/target/site/serenity/serenity-summary.html'
              ArtifactName: 'Single page report'
              publishLocation: 'Container'

          - task: publishhtmlreport@1
            displayName: Publish HTML report
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              htmlType: 'genericHTML'
              htmlPath: '$(agent.builddirectory)/s/target/site/serenity/serenity-summary.html'

          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'    

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
            displayName: 'Publish pipeline artifact'
            inputs:
              artifactName: 'drop'
              targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

At the moment of running an Azure manual job I'm getting the same issues after the 40 seconds.
I have done many changes, but always get the same errors.
Does anybody can help me with this?

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: The path you're providing is invalid. You'll have to review the structure of the repo to determine what the correct path is supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following `CmdLine@2` task after your `Maven@4` task. It will print out the file structure of the `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` folder. Then you can check and find the right file path.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      script: |
        cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
        tree
```

Comment: I did that, but I'm receiving: Skipping step due to condition evaluation.

Comment: Hi @nosequeweaponer,  if you add the `CmdLine@2` task after your `Maven@4` task and the `CmdLine@2` task  is skipped due to condition evaluation, it seems the `Maven@4` task is not successful. I edited the answer to add the  `condition: succeededOrFailed()` , you can try it again and this time the task should run.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is mentioning the exact problem, the path provided is invalid.
I suggest one of the following:

1. If the build machine isn't MS hosted, connect to the server during
   the build run and see the exact path you should send
2. Add a CMD / PowerShell step to show the tree of where your code is
   running to get full context of what needs to be sent.